Desarrollar una función que elimine el elemento que ocupa una determinada posición de un arreglo de enteros
#include<stdio.h>
void mostrarvec(int *,int);
void Eliminaryachicarvec(int *,int);
int main()
{
    int v[]={10,20,40,50,60};
    mostrarvec(v,5);
    Eliminaryachicarvec(v,5);
    mostrarvec(v,5);
    return 0;
}

void mostrarvec(int *vec,int ce)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<ce;i++)
    {
        printf("  %d  ",*vec);
        vec++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void Eliminaryachicarvec(int *v,int ce)//si deseara que se repita tiene que retornar ce-1
{
    int pos;
    printf("Ingrese la posicion que desea eliminar:\n");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    //v=v+pos-1;
    while((pos-1)<ce)
    {
        *v=*(v+1);
       //v++;
        pos++;
    }
}

Detalles:Tengo problemas con la condición para iterar y no sé si hay fallas de lógica
La consigna es la siguiente:
"Desarrollar una función que elimine el elemento que ocupa una determinada posición de un arreglo
de enteros"

Si por eliminar te refieres a mover todos los elementos una posición menos. Por ejemplo, pasar de: 1, 2, 3, 4; a 1, 3, 4. La solución es la siguiente:
for (int i = posicion + 1; i < largo; i++) {
    arreglo[i - 1] = arreglo[i];
}

arreglo[largo - 1] = 0;

posicion sería la posición del elemento a eliminar y largo el tamaño del arreglo.

*#include<stdio.h>
void mostrarvec(int *,int);
void Eliminaryachicarvec(int *,int);
int main()
{
    int v[]={10,20,40,50,60};
    mostrarvec(v,5);
    Eliminaryachicarvec(v,5);
    mostrarvec(v,4);
    return 0;
}

void mostrarvec(int *vec,int ce)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<ce;i++)
    {
        printf("  %d  ",*vec);
        vec++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void Eliminaryachicarvec(int *v,int ce)//si deseara que se repita tiene que retornar ce-1
{
    int pos, *aux;//necesito un puntero local para la condición del while
    printf("Ingrese la posicion que desea eliminar:\n");
    scanf("%d",&pos);
    //v=v+pos-1;
    aux=v+(pos-1);//el puntero guarda la posición//direccion del otro puntero
    while(aux<v+ce)
    {
        *aux=*(aux+1);
        aux++;
       //v++;
        //pos++;
    }
}*

